# ctables not found when using metpy.plots to import SkewT

Tags: python, cartopy, weather, metpy

Error occurring when attempting to import SkewT from metpy.plots. Saw similar issues from 2020, but I believe they should be resolved in current versions of MetPy. Any help to solve would be greatly appreciated!

```
from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from metpy.plots import SkewT
from metpy.units import pandas_dataframe_to_unit_arrays, units
import numpy as np
from siphon.simplewebservice.wyoming import WyomingUpperAir
```

Error generated:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 4
      1 from datetime import datetime
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 4 from metpy.plots import SkewT
      5 from metpy.units import pandas_dataframe_to_unit_arrays, units
      6 import numpy as np

File /Applications/anaconda3/envs/geodata/lib/python3.11/site-packages/metpy/plots/__init__.py:19
     16 from .wx_symbols import *  # noqa: F403
     17 from ..package_tools import set_module
---> 19 __all__ = ctables.__all__[:]  # pylint: disable=undefined-variable
     20 __all__.extend(declarative.__all__)  # pylint: disable=undefined-variable
     21 __all__.extend(patheffects.__all__)  # pylint: disable=undefined-variable

NameError: name 'ctables' is not defined
```

Comment: See https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/issues/1404, which version of cartopy and metpy do you have installed?

Comment: Running MetPy 1.6.1. CartoPy is 0.22.0.

Comment: What version of matplotlib do you have installed? Can you share somewhere the output for `conda list --export -n geodata` ?